# Is there a way stop the "." (period) acting as a word breaker in FullText Indexes?

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I know the period is a word breaker however I want to be able to search the fulltext catalog for a field containing the phrase "ASP.Net" or similar.
Currently my search returns 'ASP' and 'Net' without them occurring consecutively in the text. I want to know if there is a way to stop the period (.) acting as a word breaker for specific searches?

My research so far just suggests I use a LIKE statement however this is not feasible as there are millions of rows with large text fields to search as quickly as possible.

Answer (score 4):

Having followed the link from the comment by [Doug Deden](https://dba.stackexchange.com/users/170408/doug-deden):

> It looks like a multi-step process, but there are some promising ideas here: [Customize the Behavior of Word Breakers with a Custom Dictionary](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/search/customize-the-behavior-of-word-breakers-with-a-custom-dictionary) and [Custom WordBreaker for SQL Server Full-text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3196937/custom-wordbreaker-for-sql-server-full-text) on Stack Overflow.

I've seen that I will need to create a custom dictionary and add the entry 'ASP.Net'. This will ensure normal word breaks aren't applied to this phrase when crawling and/or searching on the full-text index.

[Create a custom dictionary (SharePoint Server 2010)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/sharepoint-server-2010/cc263242(v=office.14))

Answer (score 0):

I spend the last day figuring out this issue. The reason why this is happening is that by default, MySQL/MariaDB collations treat space(" "), periods("."), and commas(",") as punctuation. Long story short, collations "weight" characters to determine how to filter or sort them. The punctuations mentioned above are considered EOL or 'stopwords.'

We need to have MySQL/MariaDB treat those punctuations as characters rather than punctuations to solve this issue.

We are presented with three solutions in the [MySQL documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/fulltext-fine-tuning.html). The first one requires changing the source code and recompiling, which isn't a very viable option for me. The second and third options are good and aren't too hard to follow.

> - Modify a character set file: This requires no recompilation. The true_word_char() macro uses a “character type” table to distinguish letters and numbers from other characters. You can edit the contents of the  array in one of the character set XML files to specify that '-' is a “letter.” Then use the given character set for your FULLTEXT indexes. For information about the  array format, see [Section 10.13.1, “Character Definition Arrays”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/character-arrays.html).

> - Add a new collation for the character set used by the indexed columns, and alter the columns to use that collation. For general information about adding collations, see [Section 10.14, “Adding a Collation to a Character Set”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/adding-collation.html). For an example specific to full-text indexing, see [Section 12.10.7, “Adding a User-Defined Collation for Full-Text Indexing”](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/full-text-adding-collation.html).

#### First things first:

We need to know which character we're trying to fix. Take a look link below and find the HEX equivalent to the character you're trying to fix. In my case, it was 2E, the period.
[https://www.eso.org/~ndelmott/ascii.html](https://www.eso.org/%7Endelmott/ascii.html)

#### Now, we need to find the collation files in the database server.

1. SSH into your server.
2. Login into your MySQL/MariaDB: `mysql -u root -p`
3. Run `Show VARIABLES LIKE 'character_sets_dir'`

The result should return a table with a value of a directory path. I was using docker, so mine came back as `usr/share/mysql/charsets`.

At this point, I opened a second terminal, but this is necessary.

#### Back in the server, outside of the MySQL/MariaDB command line:

1. Navigate to the directory path the previous query returned. You'll find an Index.xml as well as other XML files.
2. Follow the first step in the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/full-text-adding-collation.html)

**NOTE:** Before continuing the second step, open latin1.xml and look closely at the `<map>` nested in `<lower>` and `<upper>`. Find the HEX equivalent character to the one you want to fix, in my case, 2E. We can then map the correct spot in the `<map>` nested inside `<ctype>`.

3. Continue to the second step in the [MySQL Documentation](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/full-text-adding-collation.html)
4. After the changes, Restart your server.

#### Assign the User-defined Collation to our database/table/column.

All we need to do is assign our collation to our database, table, or column. In my case, I just needed to assign it to two columns, so I ran the following command:
`ALTER TABLE laravel_fulltext MODIFY indexed_title TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_fulltext_ci, MODIFY indexed_content TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_fulltext_ci;`

Here are some links that might be helpful:
https://mariadb.com/kb/en/setting-character-sets-and-collations/
https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-syntax.html

**This should solve your problem if you don't have any existing data in the table.**

#### If you do have existing data and you try to run the query above, you might have gotten an error similar to the one below:

`SQLSTATE[22007]: Invalid datetime format: 1366 Incorrect string value: '\xE2\x80\x93 fr...' for column`.

The issue here is due to attempting to convert a 4byte character into a 3byte character. To solve this, we need to convert our data from 4bytes to binary, then to 3bytes(latin1). For more info, [check out this link.](https://coderwall.com/p/gjyuwg/mysql-convert-encoding-to-utf8-without-garbled-data)

Run the following query in the mysql/mariadb command line:
`UPDATE laravel_fulltext SET indexed_content = CONVERT(CAST(CONVERT(indexed_content USING utf8) AS BINARY) USING latin1);`

Then follow it with:
`ALTER TABLE laravel_fulltext MODIFY indexed_title TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_fulltext_ci, MODIFY indexed_content TEXT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_fulltext_ci;`

We are done. We can now search a term with our character, and our database engine will match against it.